# Lambda function syntax in JavaScript without curly braces

Tags: javascript, function, lambda

I just found out that the following (awesome) syntax is accepted by Firefox

```
f = function(x) x+1;
f(17) //gives 18
```

Does anyone know what the hell is going on here? Is this in any standard? Do other browsers also accept it? (I tested IE 8 and it gave me syntax error)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't part of a standard.  The documentation is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.8#Expression_closures_%28Merge_into_own_page.2fsection%29

There's discussion about adding some syntax along these lines or even shorter to the standard.  See http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:shorter_function_syntax

Comment: The expression closures documentation link has changed to a new [one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Expression_Closures).

Answer (score 1):

The braces are being omitted, just as you can for other control structures that take a block (`if`,`for`). It's part of standard syntax for those, perhaps not for functions. One could check the spec I guess.

The convention is that if braces are omitted, the block is the following single statement (*only* one statement).

For example

```
if(x) g=1;
```

is equivalent to

```
if(x){ g=1; }
```

However, note that

```
if(x) g=1; f=2;
```

is NOT equivalent to

```
if(x){ g=1; f=2; }
```

it is actually

```
if(x){ g=1; } f=2;
```

I avoid the braceless construct, personally, since it can lead to maintainability problems when the code is modified by people who don't know how this works.

Comment: Not just the braces. The return statement is omited too!

Comment: @missingno I saw that too on @Boris's link. It's a pretty handy shorthand for functions!