# Chrome throwing Javascript error not present on Firefox that completely breaks Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [Vex.js](https://github.com/hubspot/vex) (it uses jquery if that helps) to set up a little modal dialogue for my site. I'm linking the script to the page and using getElementById(I was told this was the best practice) to register a button click that will popup the dialogue. Everything works fine in FF, but on Chrome it doesn't work at all, and when I check the console I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on line 1 col 1.

My code looks like this:

```
function popup() vex.dialog.open({
    message: 'Enter your username and password:',
    input: "",
    buttons: [
        $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
            text: 'Login'
        })
    ],
    callback: function(data) {
        if (data === false) {
            return console.log('Cancelled');
        }
        return console.log('Username', data.username, 'Password', data.password);
    }
});


document.getElementById("sharebutton").onclick = popup;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how that would work in any browser... your `popup` function is missing opening and closing curly braces.

Comment: Mind playing tricks on me....thank you

Comment: This line `function popup() vex.dialog.open({` is not proper Javascript syntax.  I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: neal: I believe this works in Firefox because it supports "expression closures" from JS 1.8: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8#Expression_closures_(Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jason P suggested, use curly braces:

```
function popup() {
    vex.dialog.open({
        message: 'Enter your username and password:',
        input: "",
        buttons: [
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                text: 'Login'
            })
        ],
        callback: function(data) {
            if (data === false) {
                return console.log('Cancelled');
            }
            return console.log('Username', data.username, 'Password', data.password);
        }
    });
}

document.getElementById("sharebutton").onclick = popup;
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by others, you can fix it by adding braces.

But more interestly is why firefox doesn't compain about it, some testing hints that function syntax is similar to if statements.

You can either use

```
if (bool) {
    statementX;
}
```

or

```
if (bool)
    statementX;
```

And the same goes with functions, so you function works because your function consists of 1 line.

See arrow_functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions
and 
[Protovis - What are these functions with no curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831655/protovis-what-are-these-functions-with-no-curly-braces)

Possibly because arrow functions work in the same manner, bracets for multiple statement, not needed for one line that firefox supports it for all function declarations.

Comment: Interesting. This possibility did cross my mind, but I dismissed it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
function popup() {
    vex.dialog.open({
        message: 'Enter your username and password:',
        input: "",
        buttons: [
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                text: 'Login'
            })
        ],
        callback: function(data) {
            if (data === false) {
                return console.log('Cancelled');
            }
            return console.log('Username', data.username, 'Password', data.password);
        });
};

document.getElementById("sharebutton").onclick = popup;
```