# May I omit curly braces in a function declaration?

Tags: php, javascript, function

Currently, I'm declaring functions in PHP like:

```
function theFunction($theVar) {
   ...
}
```

And in JavaScript like:

```
function theFunction(theVar) {
   ...
}
```

Can I omit the curly braces when the function only contains one line? Like:

```
function theFunction($theVar)
   doSomething();
```

And:

```
function theFunction(theVar)
   doSomething();
```

Comment: It would have been quicker to try and see what happens

Comment: No: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: no. you can do that for things like loops and if/else statements, but not function definitions

Comment: As for javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919351/lambda-function-syntax-in-javascript-without-curly-braces

Comment: A trivial question you could have answered yourself in no time at all.

Comment: @LeeBurrows I thought it would be useful as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, that's not allowed by either language.

They both allow it for single-statement `if()`s and loops, but not for functions (and in the case of PHP, not for classes either).

But even if it was allowed, I'd strongly recommend against it; the braces are there for a reason, to aid readability and avoid ambiguity. I'd recommend always using them for `if()`s and loops for the same reason, even though they're not strictly required there.

Languages like Python get away without braces because they have very strict indentation rules. Without those rules, a language need braces (or some other block marker); if you don't use them, you run a very high risk of your code having logic errors.

Answer (score 3):

No. The curly braces are required. (Try it and see for yourself).

Comment: @CamilStaps What do you mean? That code gives an error in Chrome.

Comment: @CamilStaps It's a Firefox extension.

Answer (score 3):

No, neither PHP nor JS support this kind of declaration. The same is with `try` and `catch` blocks, which for some reason always require curly braces, even though condition and loop statements do not.

Comment: @CamilStaps, which browser are you using? I'm on Chrome and the snippet does nothing until I add the braces.

Comment: Ah, I'm on Firefox. That explains.

Comment: You can check out [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) - it uses code identation to delimit blocks and compiles to JS.

Comment: This explains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919351/lambda-function-syntax-in-javascript-without-curly-braces

Answer (score 0):

No, function declarations require a block regardless of how main statements are contained within.

```
function f()
    console.log(x); // error: unexpected identifier
```